# global variable not being used by functions

Tags: python, tkinter

I defined these global variables:

```
value1 = ""
value = ""
```

Both variables are being used in two different functions:

```
def function1():
  ...
  value1 = widget.get(selection1[0])

def function2():
  ...
  value = widget.get(selection0[0])
```

However when i try to use these variables in a third function:

```
def function1():
  if value1 != "":
    if value != "":
      print(value1 + " | " + value
  else:
      print("Bar")
```

I only get a `|` instead of the variables, which should be filled instead.

Comment: If a function contains an assignment to a variable, that variable is local by default.  You need an explicit `global` statement in the function to change that.

Comment: `def function1(): global value1; global value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As jasonharper's comment mentions, you need to use the `global` keyword to reference the global variable, otherwise you make a new scoped variable.

### Without global:

```
x = 3

def setToFour():
    x = 4
    print(x)

print(x)
setToFour()
print(x)
```

Output:

```
>> 3
>> 4
>> 3
```

The function makes its own `x`, sets it to 4, and prints it. The global `x` is left unchanged.

### With global:

```
x = 3

def setToFour():
    global x
    x = 4
    print(x)

print(x)
setToFour()
print(x)
```

Output:

```
>> 3
>> 4
>> 4
```

The function is told to use the global `x` rather than making its own `x`, sets it to 4, then prints it. The global `x` was directly modified, and maintains its new value.

Answer (score 1):

premising that I believe you are using tkinter, you don't need any global assignment.

You need a object oriented approach and the right tool, such as as StringVar(), or IntVar() depends on nature of your variable.

see below, def callback(self), is your function1

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,):

        super().__init__()

        self.master.title("Hello World")

        self.value = tk.StringVar()
        self.value1 = tk.StringVar()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1,)

        f = tk.Frame()

        tk.Label(f, text = "Value").pack()
        tk.Entry(f, bg='white', textvariable=self.value).pack()

        tk.Label(f, text = "Value1").pack()
        tk.Entry(f, bg='white', textvariable=self.value1).pack()

        w = tk.Frame()

        tk.Button(w, text="Print", command=self.callback).pack()
        tk.Button(w, text="Reset", command=self.on_reset).pack()
        tk.Button(w, text="Close", command=self.on_close).pack()

        f.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)
        w.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)


    def callback(self):

        if self.value1.get():
            if self.value.get():
                print(self.value1.get() + " | " + self.value.get())
        else:
            print("Foo")

    def on_reset(self):
        self.value1.set('')
        self.value.set('')

    def on_close(self):
        self.master.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
app = App()
app.mainloop()
```